# Leaflet circleMarker popup is now showing

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markers

I can't seem to get CircleMarkers to show their associated popups in Leaflet.  Here's what I am doing:

```
 var markerGroup;
 fetch("<FILE_NAME_REMOVED>").then(function(response){
           return response.text();
      }).then(function(text){

       var lines = text.split("\n");
       var markerArray = [];

        for (var i=1; i<lines.length; i++) {
          var parts = lines[i].split(",");
            if (typeof parts[2] !='undefined') {

              marker =  new L.CircleMarker([parts[3],parts[2]], {
                                             radius: 4,
                                             color: 'red',
                                             opacity: 0.95,
                                             weight: 1.2,
                                             dashArray: "2,3",
                                             fillOpacity: 0.2
          }).bindPopup("I am at " + parts[0] + "," + parts[1]);
             markerArray.push(marker);
         };
       }

       markerGroup = L.featureGroup(markerArray).addTo(map);
          map.fitBounds(markerGroup.getBounds());
         }).catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
       });
```

The popups are just not showing up - in fact when I click on the circles the map just zooms in.  If I replace L.CircleMarker with just L.Marker though it works fine, but I actually need circles.

I even tried adding an on click function to the markers, still nothing.

Could someone please help?  I am using leaflet 1.3.4.

**EDIT:**

I didn't mention (because I did't think it mattered) that the markers are added last to the map but the map has a geoJson layer as well.  I've noticed (by accident) that the popups do show up just fine over the area of the map not covered by the geoJson layer.  This is strange to me because the geojson layer is set to back from the beginning:

```
         var datalayer;
          $.getJSON("<FILE_NAME_REMOVED>",function(data){
              datalayer = L.geoJson(data ,{
                     onEachFeature: function(feature, featureLayer) {

                       featureLayer.setStyle({fillColor: 'white'});
                       featureLayer.setStyle({weight:1});
                       featureLayer.setStyle({fillOpacity:0.1});
                       featureLayer.bringToBack();
                    }
                   }).addTo(map);
                map.fitBounds(datalayer.getBounds());
          });
```

Comment: Does a single `L.CircleMarker` added directly to the map work? And how about trying a `L.layerGroup` instead of `L.featureGroup`.

Comment: Thanks peeebeee, but neither suggestion solved the problem.  I tried adding a CircleMarker like this  marker =  new L.CircleMarker([ 39.072765000000004, -84.345795], { radius: 10, color: 'green', }).bindPopup(String("DOES THIS WORK??")).addTo(map);  but clicking on it only results in zooming, not opening the popup.